# Are there any practical mean of zeroth-order square term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, heat-equation

According to Evans' PDE (351 page), for a linear parabolic equation,the second order term describes diffusion, first order term describes transport , and the zeroth order term describes creation or depletion.

But when I am in $u_t=\Delta u +u^2$, I really don't know what the $u^2$ is.I just be curious about it .

Comment: It's no longer a linear parabolic equation when you add $u^2$. This terms breaks linearity so if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are both solutions to the PDE then $u_1+u_2$ is no longer a solution.

Comment: @Winther I know, I just want to know whether it has some practical (physical)mean.